# Bootstrap Page Scaling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've recently been learning web dev, and am currently building the foundations for an idea I have.
I'm using a flask back-end with bootstrap/ html

I had a basic login system build, it looked as follows [image]

I then realised I need to link a stylesheet for bootstrap, so i did, putting this into the head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  integrity = 'sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm'
  crossorigin = 'anonymous'>
```

This changed the webpage to look as follows [image]

As a result of the stylesheet, the navigation bar is working better, but the 'scaling' of the page seems to be lower, and all the elements on the page look zoomed out

I also tried adding an additional stylesheet, after the bootstrap stylesheet

```
<link rel = 'stylesheet' 
  href = 'custom.css'
  type = 'text/css'>
```

that contains

```
h1 {
font-size: 250px;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But things tagged  still don't seem to be following this.

Comment: can you add this line `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`  inside `<head>`

Comment: given that a go, no noticeable change

Comment: codes are not enough to help, Try to troubleshoot by browser inspect, or share your code in sandbox or ...